# Heap / Stack and multiple processes

Tags: memory, memory-management, process

Say I have two process p1,p2 runnning as a part of my application.

Say p1 is running initially executing function f1() and then f1() calls f2().With the invocation of f2() process p2 starts excuting

What I want to confirm is it that :-
1)Do we have seperate stack for different process?

2)Do we have seperate heap for different process? or do different process share same heap?

3)As we know that for a 32 bit OS do for **every** process the size of virtual memory is 4GB .So is it that for every process which has 4GB as virtual memory this 4GB is partitioned into heap,stack,text,data

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) Yes, each process gets its own stack.

2) Yes, each process gets its own heap.

3) I don't think you get the whole 4GB. Some of it is reserved for kernel stuff.

Comment: As Kaizen pointed out that a 32 bit OS has 4 GB (because 2^32 ?) does it mean that each process gets a 4GB (minus reserved stuff) ? How is that handled by the OS?

Comment: (1) Yes, separate stack -- because it needs to switch the context (process) so that more than one program can run in a machine and all process can use the max memory possible (after giving up something to OS)

(2) Yes, separate heap -- because everyone needs a max possible memory

(3) Not the entire 4GB (in a 32 bit machine). Here is where the concept of virtual memory comes into picture.  Because everyone needs OS support, out of 32 bit address space some has to go for OS code and data.

Answer (score 2):

- The virtual memory for a process will
  be different from other process.
- Every process will get 4GB of virtual
  address space  ( in 32 bit windows
  machine) and out of which you can use
  2GB of user space ( remaining is for
  kernel). For stack, heap, static data storage and even loading the DLLs. (This is 3GB if you use large address space)
- Every process will get separate heap,
  stack independent of other process.

Answer (score 1):

There are other limitations to consider in Java too, such as only being able to address arrays using Integer.MAX_VALUE at most.  This limits you to about 2GB in a lot of areas relating to memory.